# Using Gradle Prevent 3rd Party Library from being on Compile Classpath

Tags: java, dependencies, gradle, dependency-management

I have a multi-project Gradle build. I have `Sub-Project-A` that depends on `Sub-Project-B`. `Sub-Project-B` has a compile time dependency on `SLF4J`. I do **not** want `Sub-Project-A` to be able to compile against any `SLF4J` libraries, but at runtime I do want `Sub-Project-B` code to be able to run.

What I thought I could do is add compile time dependencies to Sub-Project-B and then add:

```
configurations {
  compile.exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
```

to Sub-Project-A. This does prevent any code from compiling against the slf4j API, but it also prevents the slf4j library from being on the Sub-Project-A runtime so as soon as code from `Sub-Project-B` is accessed I get a ClassNotFoundException.

Since this has been so hard to get working I think I must be doing something wrong, but this doesn't feel like an unreasonable setup to have. I only want one of the subprojects in my build to be able to access a 3rd party library at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will need to exclude it and then re-include it. I can't see any way to do this in a single step.

As a slight modification to [erdi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16081953/116639), you could re-include the whole of B's dependencies in A's runtime configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(':A')) {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }
    runtime project(':A')
}
```

That is a little less repetitive.

Comment: This works really well except I've now found that a bunch of other depedencies I have configured also end up pulling in slf4j so this solution doesn't end up working anyways. Marking this as the correct solution since in my limited case I outlined I think this is definitely the best way to handle this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should probably exclude the slf4j dependency when defining dependency on Sub-Project-B and then add slf4j dependency to runtime configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(':Sub-Project-B')) {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }
    runtime 'org.slf4j:...:...'
}
```